# 1 post OR 1 posts

Tags: word-choice

[image]

I wanted to make a suggestion to change it to 1 post on [MetaStackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) but I want to know which one is the best choice or if it is even correct.

This is on the User profile, is it supposed to be 1 post?

Comment: Likely the text has a blank space where the number of posts is inserted just before presentation.  It allows for any number to be inserted there.  This is an arrangement that is commonly used, even though it can result in a minor syntax error.

Comment: Grammar would say "1 post".  But the programmer provided for "__ posts" and then the software fills in the appropriate number.  In almost all cases, the number filled in is at least 2.  Surely there are more important things to criticize that this.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: "1 post" is correct. This is something that is easy for programmers do allow for. Or the need to differentiate between "post" and "posts" can be avoided by turning it around - "Posts: 1"

Comment: Lazy coders sometime use (e.g.) `post(s)` when they can't be bothered to write code that checks for one item or more than item.